# How do I transfer an SSL certificate to a new server

Tags: godaddy, security-certificate

I have a site running on GoDaddy shared hosting, which is going to be moved over to a VPS. The site has a SSL certificate from GoDaddy.

How can I move over the certificate in a seamless way, so that the certificate is there, and all I have to do is change the DNS over?

Comment: Do you have root access to the shared server? Is the SSL certificate a shared one or a domain-specific one?

Comment: I don't have root access to the shared server (it's shared hosting after all!)
I assume its domain-specific, but how would I know?

Comment: (Oops! I meant shell access.) To find out if it's a shared certificate, either a) check your account history to see if you paid for a private SSL certificate or b) browse to your site using the https address and examine the certificate by clicking the lock icon in your browser; it will have GoDaddy's address in the 'Subject name' area if it's a shared one, and your address if it's a private one. If it's a private certificate, you can transfer it in the way Paul describes below. If it's a shared one, you'll need to purchase a new private SSL certificate for the VPS server.

Comment: For the record, I do have shell access, and its private certificate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GoDaddy SSL Certificates Help document entitled "Rekey certificate" may help you: https://www.godaddy.com/help/rekey-certificate-4976. *Note that following this document will result in old cert being revoked and new cert being issued.*

Comment: So if I "re-key" the certificate, that will allow me download the public key, private key, etc.? 
Will I be able to install it on both servers at the same time?

Comment: "The CSR contains your certificate-application information, including your public key. The CSR is generated with your Web server software, which will also create your public/private key pair used for encrypting and decrypting secure transactions." http://help.godaddy.com/topic/746/article/5343 It will exist on both servers at the same time, but once it's installed on the second on the first one won't be valid any more.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if GoDaddy is hosting Windows Virtual Private Server (IIS Web Server). If your server is Windows/IIS, you can export the PKCS12 cert with private key (password protected) and then import into another Windows IIS Server using instructions like those posted at digicert: [How to Import and Export SSL Certificates in IIS 7](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm) - see the "Exporting/Backing Up to a .pfx File" section. Document summary:

- Open Certificates MMC Snap-In for Local Computer Certificate Store
- Export the Cert *WITH PRIVATE KEY* to password-protected *.pfx file (PKCS12 format)
- Import the *.pfx file into another Windows system using same Certificates MMC Snap-In (password required to import *.pfx file).
- Choose imported cert in IIS to assign to specific web site(s).

If you're using other Web Server software or other OS, there will be a different process for copying the cert with private key for use on another system.